# Error CS0534 - does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have the 4 following classes:

```
public abstract class Base
{
     abstract public void DoIt();
}

public class TW: Base {}
public class RW: TW 
{
    public override void DoIt() {}
}
public class IW: TW
{
    public override void DoIt() {}
}
```

Usage:

```
var transaction = new TW();
transaction.DoIt();
```

I am not clear why I am getting the following error:

> Error CS0534  'TW' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   'Base.DoIt()'

If all the "leaves" derived classes (RW and IW) overrides it, why also (TW) need to override it? I may missing something since I remember that it was not a must. I do not want to override it in TW since I do not have any valid implementation to write there.

I was expecting to have the ability to write something like:

```
public override abstract void DoIt();
```

What is the correct implementation?

**UPDATE:**

According to answers I got and due to some limitation, I will have to implement it as following:

```
public override void DoIt()
{
    //Not getting to this code, it is overriden by the derived classes
}
```

Is that acceptable?
I feel that maybe something in the architecture is wrong if I am getting into a such situation.

Comment: What would you expect `new TW().DoIt()` to do? It absolutely *is* a requirement that a concrete subclass ensures there are no remaining abstract members. Perhaps you want `TW` to be abstract as well? (It doesn't help that your code doesn't specify any access modifiers, either. Please fix the post so that the *only* error is the one you're interested in.)

Comment: Actually nothing. Only, the derived classes will do there jobs

Comment: Class tw muste be also abstract or have to implement DoIt otherwise you get an error.

Comment: "Actually nothing" suggests you should provide a no-op implementation. If you don't want anyone to be able to create an instance of just `TW`, that should be abstract.

Comment: @Jon Skeet , thanks for your comment, I fix it

Comment: @ascholz, I cannot make it abstract since I am instantiating it.

Comment: @ascholz: If you're instantiating it directly then you *must* implement all abstract inherited members. If you need to add a no-op implementation, do so. Your question about "leaf" classes suggests you're not really clear on the purpose of abstract... it's meant to tell the compiler "It's okay to call this method - I know that it will be implemented in whatever object I call it on." That wouldn't be the case with `TW` here.

Comment: And no, trying to return a value from a void method isn't acceptable, nor is the lack of a space between `override` and `void`... I know you may feel it's unimportant because it's "just" a Stack Overflow post, but the aim of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository of high-quality questions and answers... posting pseudo-code hurts that aim.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's by mistake. Actually  the real code returns a value. I just wanted to simplify the question and copy it from my source code.

Comment: In terms of your final question, as to whether it's "acceptable" - well, it works. But it's odd that you have a class derived from `Base` (in this case `TW`) that you want to instantiate but doesn't *really* want to implement `DoIt`. Unfortunately from the very limited context we don't know whether that's just "a bit odd" or a symptom of a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `TW` to be an abstract class, but you don't want to provide a "real" implementation of `DoIt`, then you should throw an exception in `DoIt` instead of returning.

```
public override void DoIt()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(
        "The DoIt() method was called on a class which does not support that method.");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to make TW an abstract class too.

```
public abstract class Base
{
     public abstract void DoIt();
}

public abstract class TW: Base {}

public class RW: TW 
{
    public override void DoIt() {}
}

public class IW: TW
{
    public override void DoIt() {}
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it abstract since I am instantiating it.

Comment: So, implement DoIt() on TW

Comment: Then you have no choice: Implement DoIt.

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited your question: Here's a new answer...

```
var transaction = new TW();
transaction.DoIt();  // compiler error because this method does not really exist.
```

In your code sample, TW inherits from Base. In Base you declared DoIt() as an abstract method. That means that it has no implementation, it is only an interface. You have to implement the method in an inherited class otherwise the compiler will complain.